# Role Specific Commands for Discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, discord

Yes, I know this question has been asking many many many times. Yet for some reason I can't get role specific commands to work for v12 of discord.js.

I've tried almost every way and for some reason it wont work...

Here is my current code:

```
bot.on('message', message=>{
 if(message.content.includes('test')) {
     if(message.member.roles.has(roleidgoeshere)) {
       message.channel.send('Yay, the author of the message has the role!');
       } else {
       message.channel.send('Nope');
       }
    }
});
```

Error:`message.member.roles.has is not a function`

I am very new to coding with JavaScript, so any help would be appreciated!
If I wasn't clear enough, I'll answer any questions in the comments to the best of my abilities

Comment: Adding the error to your question is very important to help answer your questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since discord.js v12 you need to access the `roles` collection using `cache` so your solution would be:

```js
if(message.member.roles.cache.has(roleidgoeshere)) {
```